"That's ONE great nephew you got there." VS "That's A great nephew you got there."
Two old ladies are having dinner. One of them(maggie) has a nephew, who is a handsome young man, kind of man who everyone would think must be out partying, but instead he walks in the restaurant where they were having dinner and he brings a flower to the dinner table. So they are suprised and the other lady says:

That's one great nephew you got there Maggie. Christmas movie (see:20:37-20:41)

"... one great nephew..." caught my attention. I wondered why she didn't say "...a great nephew...".
Did she say "..ONE.." instead of "..A..", because she wanted to emphasize "His behaviour is very good"?
Or
Did Maggie really have one nephew, and did the other woman refer to that only "one" nephew, meaning "I know you have only one nephew and luckily he is a great one."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one

It's a USA rural/regional/informal dialect kind of saying.

"Another niece like him"? Only "one" niece, and luckily he turns out?

Yes, it's right there in the dictionary.

The indefinite article "a" is a substitute for the number one. Saying "I have a dog" is essentially saying "I have one dog".
Using 'one' instead of the indefinite article tends to be in exclamations and is a linguistic and stylistic choice that adds emphasis and intensity. It doesn't really suggest uniqueness - if you have one of something it doesn't mean there aren't more. But it does make it sound more remarkable.

one when used like that could be paraphrased as "a fine example of what  members of the set expressed by {noun phrase} should be."

That's one great nephew you have there.

He is a fine example of "great nephew".

That's one right purty vehicle.

That is certainly a very pretty vehicle.  [southern rural]

That's one ugly spider bite you got there.

As ugly spider bites go, that one is certainly a fine example.

It could be used in the negative sense "That's one ugly dog you got there"

@Mari-LouA  Seems you didn't get as far as  my last example. ;-)

One ugly bite... mean bite...nasty bite but defining it a fine example? I suppose so.

@Mari-LouA Yes. One of the meanings of "fine" is "very good" or "excellent".  Something can be an excellent example of something bad.  Stalin is a fine example of a despot.
